# Can you use printf() in Java for a float and not have trailing zeroes, but still have all necessary decimals?

Tags: java, printf

So if I have the float variable `interval` and I want to print it, I want it to print with all of the necessary figures and no extra.

If I use `System.out.printf("%f", interval);` where `float interval = 15` I get an output of `15.000000`.

I can fix that by using `System.out.printf("%2.0f", interval)` to which I get an output of `15`, but if I do that then where `float interval = 12.05f` I get an output of `12`.

My assignment requires me to use printf().